# Pass ngfor value to the image

Tags: angular, dart, ngfor

My JSON string value is shown below, I am loading the country name to the Select control. This is working fine, now whenever a country is selected relevant image should be passed to the IMG tag example, if country India is selected then image should be like this

```
<img src="india.png">
```

If England is selected then the image tag should

```
<img src="hello.png">
```

Below is the JSON value I am getting from web service call.

```
[{
"Name": "England ",
"ImageFile": hello.png,
"Id": 1
},
{
"Name": "South Africa",
"ImageFile": test.png,
"Id": 2
}, 
{
"Name": "India",
"ImageFile": india.png,
"Id": 2
}]
```

In Dart I had written the function to get Country Id, the value is coming correctly in dart function. Now I need to change the image value according to the country selected

```
   <label style="alignment: center" for="countries">Country
        <select class="form-control" id="countries" *ngIf="sCountries.length > 0" [ngModel]="0" (ngModelChange)="selectCountry($event)">
            <option value="0">All</option>
            <option *ngFor="let country of sCountries" value="{{country['Id']}}">{{country['Name']}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: `<img [src]="country.ImageFile"> `

Comment: @Subramanian Which place you need to `img` tag inside `select option` or outside?

Comment: Image tag is in separate DIV

Comment: @Edison if i am not wrong image tag is not in the ngfor then how is this going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind whole country object with ngModel which won't required you to manually iterate over your loop to fetch selected country object. Two-way binding has great power.

```
<label style="alignment: center" for="countries">Country
    <select class="form-control" id="countries" *ngIf="sCountries.length > 0" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
        <option *ngFor="let country of sCountries" [value]="country">{{country['Name']}}</option>
    </select>
</label>

<ng-container *ngIf="selectedCountry"> 
    <img [src]="selectedCountry.ImageFile">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your `selectCountry` method set selected  country in your component something like

```
selectedCountry:any

selectCountry(countryId){
var country=this.sCountries.find(c=>c.Id==countryId)
this.selectedCountry=country;
}
```

then change image tag to

```
<img [src]="selectedCountry?.ImageFile">
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzhw4k)

Comment: In the Select Option I had given the value like this value="{{country['Id']}}" that means in the selectCountry function we will be getting the int value.

Comment: then you can find country by id like `var country=this.sCountries.find(c=>c.id==id)` and set as selected check out updated ans

Comment: Nice solution, but I am using Dart language... Anyhow I got the idea, I will try this and get back to you